# How can I extract the result for all students with their test result in one row

Tags: mysql, sql

I have one table contains a  big list of student test result  with the different columns, such as: student id, student name,test ID, test date and test result( Table-1).
Table-1:

[image]

Result I expected like Table-2 [The expected result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jvdCq.png)

Comment: provide sample data and your expected output in table format, not in image

Comment: Please read [Why not upload images of code on SO when asking a question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557) and [edit] your question to include code **and** data as text, not images.

Comment: Read [ask] and create a TEXTUAL [mcve]

Comment: My apologies for missing the table-2 in my question, I need to have get result for each student for whatever test they attended in one row, the result looks like: studentid /M1 test date/M1 score/MA test/MA score/GA test/GA score,etc.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly, you should try to use the query selector:

```
SELECT StudentID, Score FROM (tablename)
```

Comment: Thank you MrAwesome, please see my comments.